# Confusion regarding sampling from probabilitiy distributions

Tags: distributions, bayesian, sampling

I am self-studying Bayesian Inference, and I am now looking at sampling from posterior distributions

For the various sampling algorithms such as **ICDF** and **Accept-reject**, my intuition is that we know the distribution *analytically*(e.g. since we need to know the inverse CDF), but we cannot directly sample from it. Is this intuition correct?

Comment: yes that's correct.

Comment: What do you mean by directly sampling? Writing $X=F^-(U)$ [ICDF] is a direct transform of a Uniform variate and a direct application of the definition of a random variable as a transform.